# Adding a table variable in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am a beginner in Dynamic SQL and trying to write a dynamic sql code in which I need to include a table variable .When I try to include the table variable I am getting an error saying that I need to include the Static variable.

Below is just part of the code

```
DECLARE @NAMES TABLE (name varchar)
DECLARE @fields varchar(max);
.
.
.
Select @fields=FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id=object_id('dbo.employees') 
order by name
SET @SQL=''
SET @SQL='Select '+ @fields
SET @SQL=@SQL + ' from dbo.test()' 
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE name IN'
SET @SQL= @SQL + '(Select name from ' 
SET @SQL=@SQL + @NAMES +')'
```

Comment: Change to TempTable

Comment: This just makes me shudder. Why do I get the feeling you are getting the fields and values as parameters? This has the tell tale signs of code that is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your SELECT to get the column names won't work at all. You need something like this:

```
DECLARE @fields nvarchar(max);
SET @fields = N'';
SELECT @fields += CASE WHEN LEN(@fields) = 0 THEN N'' ELSE N', ' END + name
  FROM sys.columns
 WHERE object_id=object_id('dbo.employees') 
 ORDER BY column_id
PRINT @fields;
```

I'm honestly not sure what the rest of your SQL is trying to do... it's trying to select the fields from the employee table from the return of a table-valued function called test()?  Where the 'name' column from that test() result set is in ... what?  You'll need to be a lot more clear before I can give you a complete answer.  One major problem is that you've never actually filled your table variable with anything, so ... I have no idea what you're going for. Knowing the definition of the Test() function would also be helpful.

But at least the above will give you the @fields variable set correctly to the list of columns in the table dbo.employee.

When doing Dynamic SQL, it really helps to write out the end resulting SQL you want, and then identify what parts of that SQL should be filled in by variable data, and work backwards.  It's then a lot easier to construct your SQL to build your dynamic SQL.

Comment: I need to pull all the column names from dbo.employees and use that columns in the select statement that would pull the same columns from dbo.test where the names of employees would match the names supplied as a parameter.
The table variable will hold all the names supplied as an argument.

I would want SQL something like

Select @fields from dbo.test where name in (Select name from @names);

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the tablevariable logic to dynamic sql

```
--You need to load @names inside dynamic sql
DECLARE @fields varchar(max);
.
.
.
Select @fields=FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id=object_id('dbo.employees') 
order by name
SET @SQL='DECLARE @NAMES TABLE (name varchar); '
SET @SQL +=' Select '+ @fields
SET @SQL=@SQL + ' from dbo.test()' 
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE name IN'
SET @SQL= @SQL + '(Select name from ' 
SET @SQL=@SQL + ' @NAMES )'
```

Or you can load into temp table and access the temptable inside dynamic sql. This means you will be loading temptable like #names and then use that in dynamic sql...

Comment: But the table variable NAMES can't be used without dynamic query.